# Search form associated attributes with joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to find a record from the records models associated models, associated model attribute.

I have a `VendorOrder` model and would like to find a `VendorOrder` (or vendor_orders, if matching criteria) by searching the `vendor_order.order.shipments.each {|shipment| shipment.shipping_label.tracking_number}`, if possible.  So searching for a tracking number.

Models:

```
VendorOrder

  belongs_to :order
  has_many :shipments

Order

  has_many :vendor_orders
  has_many :shipments
  has_many :shipping_labels

Shipment

  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :vendor_order
  belongs_to :shipping_label

ShippingLabel

  belongs_to :order
  has_one :shipment
```

I have in controller,

```
@vendor_orders = VendorOrder.joins(:order).merge(Order.where(order_status: "paid")).order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:vendor_page], per_page: 25)

    if params[:search]
      @vendor_orders = VendorOrder.search(params[:search])
    else
      @vendor_orders = VendorOrder.joins(:order).merge(Order.where(order_status: "paid")).order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:vendor_page], per_page: 25)
    end
```

In `VendorOrder` model,

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['shipments.map {|shipment| shipment.shipping_label.tracking_number} LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

View:

```
<%= form_tag vendor_orders_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Error:

```
Couldn't find all VendorOrders with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>["shipments.map {|shipment| shipment.shipping_label.tracking_number} LIKE ?", "%99999999999999999999%"]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2).):
```

Obviously I am not fully understanding how this works.  I have up until now only made search forms where the search within one model for a string.

How can I search through multiple layers of models but making sure a VendorOrder is the front model being searched for?

### Update:

Using jvillian post:

Doing:

in model:

```
class << self

    def find_by_tracking_number(tracking_number)
      joins(:shipments).
        where(shipments: {
          id: Shipment.find_by(
            shipping_label: ShippingLabel.where(tracking_number: tracking_number)
          )
        })
    end

  end
```

controller:

```
@vendor_orders = VendorOrder.joins(:order).merge(Order.where(order_status: "paid")).order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:vendor_page], per_page: 25)

    if params[:search]
      @vendor_orders = VendorOrder.find_by_tracking_number(params[:search])
    else
      @vendor_orders =  VendorOrder.
                          joins(:order).
                          merge(Order.where(order_status: "paid")).
                          order(created_at: :desc).
                          paginate(page: params[:vendor_page], per_page: 25)
    end
```

works to get things up and running but i run into the issue of no results.

Entering the numbers "99999999999999999999" should garner about 10 results but 0 appear.

on submit:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"99999999999999999999"}
```

does its magic:

```
SELECT  "shipments".* FROM "shipments" WHERE "shipments"."shipping_label_id" IN (SELECT "shipping_labels"."id" FROM "shipping_labels" WHERE "shipping_labels"."tracking_number" = $1) LIMIT $2[0m  [["tracking_number", "99999999999999999999"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

But then nothing after that, it just renders the page.

At this moment, there are about 10 VendorOrders that have `shipments.map { |shpiment| shipment.shipping_label.tracking_number }` that == "99999999999999999999"

Any reason why nothing is appearing? Missing something in my code to append the all results?

Comment: Can you try this query?
`VendorOrder.joins(order: [shipments: :shipping_label]).where('\`shipping_labels\`.\`tracking_number\` LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")`

Comment: Hm this is on the right track now, wasn't thinking of doing that... but this gave me: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
VendorOrder.
  joins(:shipments).
  where(shipments: {
    id: Shipment.find_by(shipping_label: ShippingLabel.find_by(tracking_number: @tracking_number))
  })
```

To break it down, assume you have your tracking number in a variable called `@tracking_number`. This:

```
ShippingLabel.find_by(tracking_number: @tracking_number)
```

...will find your `ShippingLabel`. And this:

```
Shipment.find_by(shipping_label: ShippingLabel.find_by(tracking_number: @tracking_number))
```

...will find your `Shipment` that `belongs_to` the `ShippingLabel`.

Then, following the [Specifying Conditions on the Joined Table](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables) section of the guide gives you the final query from way up above.

You might use this in the controller something like:

```
if params[:search]
  @vendor_orders =  VendorOrder.
                      joins(:shipments).
                      where(shipments: {
                        id: Shipment.find_by(
                          shipping_label: ShippingLabel.find_by(
                            tracking_number: params[:search]
                          )
                        )
                      })
else
  @vendor_orders =  VendorOrder.
                      joins(:order).
                      merge(Order.where(order_status: "paid")).
                      order(created_at: :desc).
                      paginate(page: params[:vendor_page], per_page: 25)
end
```

Or, you could put (some of) this in the `VendorOrder` model, something like:

```
class VendorOrder < ApplicationRecord 

  class << self 

    def find_by_tracking_number(tracking_number)
      joins(:shipments).
        where(shipments: {
          id: Shipment.find_by(
            shipping_label: ShippingLabel.find_by(tracking_number: tracking_number)
          )
        })
    end

  end

end
```

And then you might use it in a controller something like:

```
if params[:search]
  @vendor_orders = VendorOrder.find_by_tracking_number(params[:search])
else
  @vendor_orders =  VendorOrder.
                      joins(:order).
                      merge(Order.where(order_status: "paid")).
                      order(created_at: :desc).
                      paginate(page: params[:vendor_page], per_page: 25)
end
```

That seems a little nicer, IMO, and hides some of the complexity from the controller.

Comment: To clarify, you're saying to put this in the model right?

Comment: See updated answer. You could certainly put (some of) this in the model. Or, you could put (all of) it in the controller.

Comment: I get "`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `total_pages' for #<VendorOrder::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000055f61b025140>)`" without using the paginate and the page won't load.  With using paginate I get..."`undefined method `total_pages' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`"

Comment: Apparently wil pagiante can't deal with arrays, which is what a search does apparently.  Looks like I just need to make a page dedicated to searching

Comment: It looks like others have had the same problem (calling `total_pages` on an `ActiveRecord_Relation`). See [this issue](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/411) for potential help. Maybe something like `VendorOrder.find_by_tracking_number(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:vendor_page], per_page: 25).total_pages`? (I'm guessing.)

Comment: Looks like using the `unless empty` worked for empty results.

Comment: Great. Please remember to upvote/accept for future searchers.

Comment: I made an update.  For some reason no results appear